# Time output in Eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, console

is there any possibility to add timestamp to every line which is printed in Eclipse console? For example when code like

`System.out.println("Hello World");`

is executed I would like to have something like this in console:

`[yy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss] Hello World`

Thank you in advance for any sugestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if third party library straightaway provides it. But you can create custom print method to achieve it and use it across the project

```
 public void customPrint(String inputToPrint){
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date now = new Date();
    String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
    System.out.println("[" + strDate + "] " + inputToPrint);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of goal is usually satisfied automatically by logging libraries like [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). With a logging library you would instantiate a logger at the class level

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

and then write your log messages through the logger:

```
LOG.debug("Here's my log message")
```

The output format is configurable, but one example of output is this:

```
2013-12-14 11:21:05.985 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] DEBUG c.s.m.i.MyClass - Here's my log message
```

Comment: FYI, when you look at LogBack as suggested, also look at [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/). That is a façade API that let's you plug and play alternate logging frameworks.